# How does this button click work in WPF MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm

I'm starting to study about WFM MVVM pattern.

But I can't understand why this `Button` click works without binding any event or action.

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPF2.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewProducts,Path=SelectedItem.ProductId}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,35,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewProducts,Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,61,0,0" Name="txtPrice" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewProducts,Path=SelectedItem.Price}" />
        <Label Content="ID" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,274" Name="label1" />
        <Label Content="Price" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,59,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Content="Name" Grid.Row="1" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,35,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

        <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Height="23" Margin="310,40,0,0" Content="Update" />

        <ListView Name="ListViewProducts" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,109,12,23"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"  >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="grdTest">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Product ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductId}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="250" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" Width="127" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public const string ProductsPropertyName = "Products";

    private ObservableCollection<Product> _products;

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return _products;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_products == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _products = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(ProductsPropertyName);
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
        {
            new Product {ProductId=1, Name="Pro1", Price=11},
            new Product {ProductId=2, Name="Pro2", Price=12},
            new Product {ProductId=3, Name="Pro3", Price=13},
            new Product {ProductId=4, Name="Pro4", Price=14},
            new Product {ProductId=5, Name="Pro5", Price=15}
        };
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I found this code from a tutorial i've read. When i click on a row from listview, the textbox values are set. And when I edit those values and click a button, the values on listview are updated.

There is no event nor command bound on the button. So how do button click update the values from listview??

Comment: That button doesn't do anything. The listbox takes care of itself.

Comment: How is that? Could you please explain more? Listview updates its value when the button is clicked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you set focus elsewhere the listbox would update. Its the fact that you are done editing the listbox that causes it to update when it loses focus.

Comment: Ohh, you're right. If the textbox loses focus, the update occurs. Thanks. I thought it has something to do with the button. =)

Comment: @RitchMelton That is correct. To add a little more detail, it is because the default value of the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property for the Text bindings is `LostFocus`.

Comment: So do you think I'm binding my items to Listview in a wrong way? Because I want to update the values with a Command?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the way you are binding. But to achieve what you want, you need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit`

Answer (score 25):

I know this is old but I was looking into this scenario and found my answer.
First, in MVVM theory the "code-behind" shouldn't have code all the code should be in the ViewModel class.
So in order to implement button click, you have this code in the ViewModel (besides the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation):

```
        public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(o => MainButtonClick("MainButton"));
        }

        private void MainButtonClick(object sender)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sender.ToString());            
        }
```

Using the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace <your namespace>.ViewModels
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        {
            if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; } 
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter ?? "<N/A>");
        }

    }
}
```

And in XAML:

> ```
> <Window.DataContext>
>     <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
> </Window.DataContext>  <Button Content="Button"  Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}"  />
> ```

Comment: @SandraK It is a class from [`System.Windows.Input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input?view=netframework-4.7.2). See [`CommandManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandmanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Is there no built-in equivalent of RelayCommand? I feel so weird adding this class to all of my WPF projects... This is essentially a mandatory copy paste if I want to use buttons

Comment: @RobertF. I've always wondered this as well; how is it possible that button clicks in WPF MVVM aren't supported out of the box?

Comment: @RobertF. you can just use a lambda. Google "C# Command pattern lambda": https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+Command+pattern+lambda

Comment: @Mariano Peinador while your answer works as a solution in general, your answer does not answer the question. The question was, why does the button works when it doesn't get bound to anything, and your answer doesn't answer that.

Comment: @KulaGGin Could you link a specific answer? I went through a couple of the search results, and none of them answers the problem. You need an `ICommand` object to bind to the `Command` property of the `Button`. No `Action` or `Action<object>` will help with that (I tried it just now). You can't specify a lambda in XAML anyways. So I am not really sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

In above sample snippet, ListView is binded to an `ObservableCollection` of Product which is internally implemented INotfiyPropertyChanged Interface. This interface is responsible for raising `PropertyChanged` event and updates binded UI element values whenever it change.

More over you can see here, the Text property of all TextBoxes are binded as  `Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewProducts,Path=SelectedItem.ProductId}`"

`Binding ElementName` - This is a markup extension which will tell XAML compiler to bind your ListView to Textbox control

`Path` - This will point to a specific property of Binded UI Element. In this case it will point to ListView.SelectedItem object property. ie. Product.ProductID

The binding mode of WPF UI element is `TwoWay` by default. So it will update both Source and Target whenever the value changes. You can try this by changing mode to `OneWay`

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,7,0,0" Name="txtID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="178" Text="{Binding ElementName=ListViewProducts,Path=SelectedItem.ProductId,Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Instead of using **bold** you can use the `code sample` tool in edit mode to describe code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` and on the `Click` event of the `Button` you need to update the binding source.

The `Button`s `Click` event is executed first before `Command`. Hence the source properties can be updated in the `Click` event. I have modified your code to demonstrate this.

Note:

1. I have written the view model in code behind for simplicity.
2. I have used the `RelayCommand` from the `MVVMLight` library.

**1st XAML Change**

```
    <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141" Height="23" Margin="310,40,0,0" Content="Update" Click="Button_Click" Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"/>
```

**2nd XAML Change**

```
    <ListView Name="ListViewProducts" Grid.Row="1" Margin="4,109,12,23"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}" >
```

**Code behind**

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WPF2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtID.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
            txtName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
            txtPrice.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
        }
    }

    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public const string ProductsPropertyName = "Products";

        private ObservableCollection<Product> _products;

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                return _products;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_products == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _products = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(ProductsPropertyName);
            }
        }

        private Product _SelectedProduct;

        public Product SelectedProduct
        {
            get { return _SelectedProduct; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedProduct = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProduct");
            }
        }


        private ICommand _UpdateCommand;

        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_UpdateCommand == null)
                {
                    _UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show( String.Format("From ViewModel:\n\n Updated Product : ID={0}, Name={1}, Price={2}", SelectedProduct.ProductId, SelectedProduct.Name, SelectedProduct.Price));
                        });
                }
                return _UpdateCommand;
            }
        }


        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _products = new ObservableCollection<Product>
            {
                new Product {ProductId=1, Name="Pro1", Price=11},
                new Product {ProductId=2, Name="Pro2", Price=12},
                new Product {ProductId=3, Name="Pro3", Price=13},
                new Product {ProductId=4, Name="Pro4", Price=14},
                new Product {ProductId=5, Name="Pro5", Price=15}
            };

        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```