# Is there any way easier to bind to a click event in a view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am about to bind the click event to a view model in .Net 5.

There are so many tutorials about this. By using the third-party MVVM Light toolkit, or by adding a class that inherits `ICommand` (just like this [How does this button click work in WPF MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117294/how-does-this-button-click-work-in-wpf-mvvm/39601781)). And the last, the most troublesome way by the original Microsoft tutorial ([Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)).

All of them are troublesome and the tutorial was long long years ago.

What's more, it seems the original Microsoft way ([Commanding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-5.0)) no longer exists in .Net 5.

I wonder whether there is an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, using a mvvm framework like Prism (not sure if these tools will work with .NET 5). The easiest way is to not re-invent the wheel, use well supported packages. AND use .NET 5 only if you really require it e.g. cross-platform needs, microservices etc. NET 5 is not an LTS version and its support will probably end by early 2022, not to mention it doesnt have a large general community support cause it just released - so unless you're looking for a specific niche advantage of .NET 5, I would recommend not developing on it. See https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the ways from your sources were and are valid approaches for different scenarios.

- Using derivatives of `ICommand` like `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand` (most MVVM frameworks offer their own implementation that differs in certain aspects but they use the same concept)
- [`CommandBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/commanding-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#commandbinding)s for [routed commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.routedcommand?view=net-5.0) like the [`ApplicationCommands`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.applicationcommands?view=net-5.0)
- [`InputBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.inputbinding?view=net-5.0)s for reacting to key gestures ([`KeyBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.keybinding?view=net-5.0)) or mouse gestures ([`MouseBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousebinding?view=net-5.0))
- Using an `EventTrigger` to call a command when a specific event is fired (`EventToCommand`)

There is also a an article on MSDN that explains the `RelayCommand` and `EventToCommand` mechanisms.

- [MVVM - Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand)

.All of these approaches still exist in .NET 5. However, if you want to use behaviors or triggers (like the abovementioned `EventToCommand`, you should use the new [*Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/)  NuGet package instead of the legacy interaction assembly shipped with *Blend*.

I would not assume that there is an *"original Microsoft way"*, it depends on your requirements. In order to bind a button click to an action on a view model, you would typically use the `RelayCommand` approach. In both your [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39601781/6181599) and the [link on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand), you can find an implementation of a `RelayCommand`. If you decide to use any MVVM framework like Caliburn.Micro, Prism or MVVM Light there is already a built-in implementation.

You would expose an `ICommand` property in your view model and initialize it e.g. in the constructor.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public MyViewModel()
   {
      MyCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteMyCommand, CanExecuteMyCommand);
   }

   public ICommand MyCommand { get; }

   private bool CanExecuteMyCommand(object obj)
   {
      // ...obj is the optional command parameter.
      // ...return whether your command can execute.
   }

   private void ExecuteMyCommand(object obj)
   {
      // ...obj is the optional command parameter.
      // ...do something.
   }

   // ...other code.
}
```

Then you can bind the command in your view. Make sure the `DataContext` of your view is set or bound to an instance of your view model, otherwise the binding will not work.

```
<Button Content="My Button" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

The command parameter is optional, I bound it to the content of the button for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need any library. But i would prefer to pick one (Prism or Mvvmcross) To actually bind click of button to Viewmodel the viewmodel must have public property of type ICommand. In view the data context must be set to the viewmodel (this step can be automated by framework)
Manually in constructor: this.DataContext =new My view model().
Last step in view:
Button Command={Binding MyICommandProperty}

Also you do not need binding to perform action on click simply use Button click=NameOfEventHandlerInCodeBehind

Comment: I prefer using the original Microsoft way while I feel strange that Microsoft design this so troublesome. I don't want to add a third-party framework (Prism or Mvvmcross)  just for this.

Comment: Prism used to be a Microsoft best practices library probably reason why it is not supported out of the box. MVVM is best practise not requirement for wpf. You don't need install library but the main benefit is that u don't need wire up your viewmodel with view (creating instance of VM and setting it to views DataContext)